# How could I hide the url of a site within an iframe?

Tags: html, url, iframe, hide

I have a site that has an iframe linking to another site with the following example iframe code:

```
 <html>
 <body>

 <iframe src="http://google.com" width="100%" height="600">

 </iframe>

 </body>
 </html>
```

So, for the above example, how could I prevent visitors from finding the url: http://google.com ?

Comment: Finding in what object? You can't remove it from the Response text, so client will always can view html-code

Comment: you can't cos google is everywhere.

Answer (score 5):

You can't. Suffice to browse the source code and see it. And even if you try to put this in an obfuscated javascript file which will dynamically set the `src` property of the iframe nothing can't be hidden from the [Net tab](http://getfirebug.com/network) in [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/). So I would recommend you not wasting your time with this.

Answer (score -1):

You can write e.g. PHP or Apache rewrite to fetch the page from backend server. This has very little CPU overhead.

Answer (score -2):

You could nest an iframe in another site / page and point the iframe on your current page to that one.

This would obfuscate it to some degree but if someone is intent on finding the URL, chances are they will.

Comment: Right click, view source.  This won't hide anything.

Comment: I'm guessing you mean view frame source? I didn't think of that :o.